# Table data from api

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get my data from the API into the table.

I've tried loops but it won't work

```
var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp, myObj, x, txt = "";
obj = { table: "login", limit: 20 };
dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        txt += "<table border='1'>"
        for (x in myObj) {
            txt += "<tr><td>" +myObj[x].name+  "</tr></td>";
        }
        txt += "</table>" 
        document.getElementById("myData").innerHTML = txt;
        console.log(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://api.github.com/users", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application//x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("x="+dbParam);
```

I would like for the table to be filled with the API data

Comment: What issue you are facing?

Comment: You have reversed order of closing `tr` and `td` tags in for..in loop. You have opening td in tr and then closing tr in td, so change closing tags and should be ok

Answer (score 1):

You are closing the `<tr>` before the `<td>`:

```
txt += "<tr><td>" +myObj[x].name+  "</tr></td>";
```

fix:

```
txt += "<tr><td>" +myObj[x].name+  "</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the API is not returning any key named - **name**

Hit this URL on browser and see all the keys in response

> https://api.github.com/users

I am changing key name to id, you may use any key which is being returned in response:

```
txt += "<table border='1'>"
  for (x in myObj) {
    txt += "<tr><td>" +myObj[x].id+  "</td></tr>";
  }
  txt += "</table>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp, myObj, x = 0, objLen, txt = "";
obj = { table: "login", limit: 20 };
dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        objLen = myObj.length;
        txt += "<table border='1'>";
        while (x < objLen) {      
            txt += "<tr>";
            for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(myObj[x])) {
                txt += "<td>" + value + "</td>";
            }
            txt += "</tr>";
            x++;
            
        }
        txt += "</table>";
        document.getElementById("myData").innerHTML = txt;
//        console.log(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://api.github.com/users", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application//x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("x="+dbParam);
```

```html
<div id="myData"></div>
```

It shows all the fetched data in the table. One login in one column. You may change the HTML and manipulate as per your need.